# Use GRUB to decide whether to boot to desktop

Tags: linux, grub, desktop-environments

I know SDDM (or others) can be set to run at boot, but is it possible to create a second GRUB entry that would boot to the normal TTY login? I know it's possible to create an entry for single-user rescue mode, but I still need one for normal multi-user.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure a different runlevel if you want to add a grub entry, or you could just modify the normal runlevel by configuring init.d or upstart.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What exactly is your operating system, distribution and version?

Comment: Arch, most recent. KDE, GRUB